# multipass running something at 100% cpu

Tags: multipass

Hi I noticed something was using 100% cpu for a long time, checked `ps aux` and saw this:

`root      8217 99.9  0.0 208160 13608 ?        Sl   11:25 165:44 /snap/multipass/2439/bin/sshfs_server 10.24.202.253 22 ubuntu /home/me/snaps/hub/snap /root/project 1000:0, 1000:0,`

The dir `/home/me/snaps/hub/snap` doesn't exist anymore (was removed it before booting today), and `multipass list` shows nothing.

I tried quiting multipass (via the sys tray icon), but that didn't help.

Only after killing it (with kill -9) it stopped.

Any idea why multipass was running this? Or what to do to prevent this from happening again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the reason why you saw the `sshfs_server` process running at 100% CPU, it is due to https://github.com/canonical/multipass/issues/1677. I'll be working on a fix for that sometime soon.

Thanks!

Comment: Ah, this makes answer more sense, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Multipass is a tool to launch and manage VMs that simulates a cloud environment.

You had to install it yourself or a package (snap type) did it when installing a third-party application

to list all the snap package you have:

```
 snap list
```

to uninstall Multipass (or other) try a:

```
sudo snap remove multipass
```

Comment: I see, I didn't realize that ~/snap was used for data of snaps. I thought it was running some old snap that i created. Thanks :)